# Find the value of the function

Tags: functions, polynomials

If we are given $x^2$$-3x+1=0$ then we have to find the value of ($x^6$$+x^4$$+x^2$$+1$)/($x^3$)  .

I tried by sustituting the values from linear equation, but got no result ........
.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{x^6+x^4+x^2+1}{x^3}=\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)+\left(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$

And you have $$x+\frac{1}{x}=3$$ square and cube this last equation to find the desired values.

Answer (score 1):

$(x^2+1)(x^4+1)/x^3$

$(x^2+1/x^2).3$

$(7.3)$

$21$